# Save email draft in .msg format with .SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using a VBA code to write an email in Outlook with the information from a PowerPoint file and saving it as a draft, in the format ".msg".

```
With OutMail                    
    .To = name_email                                     
    'Add file likethis                    
    .Attachments.Add ("C:... " & numb_slide & ".pptx")                    
    .Subject = "... " & date_c & " | Open Tasks " & name_project & " | Feedback ... " & dead_line_date & ",..."                    
    .Body = StrBody                                    
    '.SaveAs "C:... " & CStr(date_c) & " | ... " & CStr(name_project) & ".msg", 5                    
    .SaveAs "C:..." & numb_slide & ".msg", 5                    
    '.Display Or use .Send                
End With
```

I have **two problems:**

**1)** When I save the file using:

```
.SaveAs "C:..." & numb_slide & ".msg", 5
```

The program does not give me an error but I cannot open the draft that was saved, the error states: [image: error when trying to open the draft]

If I create a normal email and save it as a draft, I can open it later.

**2)** If I change the way I save the file, like:

```
.SaveAs "C:... " & CStr(date_c) & " | ... " & CStr(name_project) & ".msg", 5
```

Or

```
.SaveAs "C:... " & date_c & " | Open Tasks " & name_project & ".msg", 5
```

It gives me the following error before finishing the task:

[image]

The variables I am writing in the name are strings, but I also tried to write them using `CStr()` to check if it would make any difference, *and it does not!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `3` instead of `5`.

From the [`olSaveAsType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olsaveastype) enumeration:

- `3` corresponds to *Outlook message format* (.msg)
- `5` corresponds to *HTML format* (.html)

Alternately, you could just drop the file type. From the [`MailItem.SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saveas) documentation,

> If the file type is not specified, the MSG format (.msg) is used.

Comment: Thank you, that works for the problem number (1)! :) Now I would like to solve problem number (2), do you have any idea about that one?

Comment: I don't think filenames can contain the `|` character.